# Design an Apple Wallet pass style card in SwiftUi

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm struggling to achieve the design of an Apple Wallet pass card in my SwiftUI app.
My goal is to have have a card with a little cutout at the top juste like on this screenshot. Thanks in advance for the help [image: apple wallet pass]

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack() {
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Ellipse()
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.2, height: 50) // adjust width and height as needed
                        .foregroundColor(.white) // assuming a white ellipse
                        .offset(y: -120) // move the ellipse up by half its height
                    Spacer()
                }
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Card")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .frame(height: 200)
                    // Rest of your VStack content
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color("BuoyPurple")) // Replace with your color
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: 300) // adjust height as needed
        }
        .padding()
```

[image]

Problem is that I can't do the shadow effect that way

Comment: What did you try so far? Can you share some code?

Comment: Yes of course I'll edit my post with what I triedd @son

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to add a shadow to the background, I would suggest using a custom `Shape` for this.

- The shape can be formed quite easily as a rounded rectangle with an inset subtracted from the top.
- One way to create the path of the inset is to use `.addQuadCurve`.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    struct CardShape: Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            let insetWidth = 50.0
            let insetHeight = 20.0
            var insetPath = Path()
            insetPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX - (insetWidth / 2), y: rect.minY))
            insetPath.addQuadCurve(
                to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX + (insetWidth / 2), y: rect.minY),
                control: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY + insetHeight)
            )
            insetPath.closeSubpath()
            return Path(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 8)
                .subtracting(insetPath)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Card")
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(height: 200)
            // Rest of your VStack content
        }
        .padding()
        .background(
            CardShape()
                .fill(.indigo) // Color("BuoyPurple"))
                .shadow(color: Color(white: 0.3), radius: 8)
        )
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]